# QuickBlocks QBSettings getting undeclared identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, quickblox, undeclared-identifier

I have included the API Frameworks but still get error : Use of undeclared identifier 'QBSettings' in AppDelegate.m file.

```
#import <FYX/FYX.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ApplicationContext.h"
#import "EnableProximityViewController.h"
#import "LoginViewController.h"




@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize loginViewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

// Set QuickBlox credentials (You must create application in admin.quickblox.com)
[QBSettings setApplicationID:11948];
[QBSettings setAuthorizationKey:@"SHdXhhjVY7BL-GtGH"];
[QBSettings setAuthorizationSecret:@"3ZYjkXTzaUfd6kLTL"];
[QBSettings setAccountKey:@"yFHpgFbxe3hjkMXmjs9sv9u"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer...

Go to App-Name.pch then add the import to the Framework file. This is how it links back.

```
       #import <Quickblox/Quickblox.h>
```

Comment: Yes, this is covered here http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS#How_to:_add_SDK_to_Xcode_and_connect_to_the_cloud